# Proposition 24 of Euclid's first book

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I don't understand a statement in Euclid's proof of Prop. I24: **Therefore the angle DFG is greater than the angle EGF.**. Is it a consequence of what?

This is the full proposition as stated here https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI24.html:

If two triangles have two sides equal to two sides respectively, but have one of the angles contained by the equal straight lines greater than the other, then they also have the base greater than the base.

[image]

*Proof*- Let ABC and DEF be two triangles having the two sides AB and AC equal to the two sides DE and DF respectively, so that AB equals DE, and AC equals DF, and let the angle at A be greater than the angle at D.

I say that the base BC is greater than the base EF.

Since the angle BAC is greater than the angle EDF, construct the angle EDG equal to the angle BAC at the point D on the straight line DE. Make DG equal to either of the two straight lines AC or DF. Join EG and FG.
I.4

Since AB equals DE, and AC equals DG, the two sides BA and AC equal the two sides ED and DG, respectively, and the angle BAC equals the angle EDG, therefore the base BC equals the base EG.
I.5

Again, since DF equals DG, therefore the angle DGF equals the angle DFG. Therefore the angle DFG is greater than the angle EGF.

Therefore the angle EFG is much greater than the angle EGF.
I.19

Since EFG is a triangle having the angle EFG greater than the angle EGF, and side opposite the greater angle is greater, therefore the side EG is also greater than EF.

But EG equals BC, therefore BC is also greater than EF.

Therefore if two triangles have two sides equal to two sides respectively, but have one of the angles contained by the equal straight lines greater than the other, then they also have the base greater than the base.

Answer (score 2):

We have already established $\angle DGF = \angle DFG$.

Note that $\angle DGF = \angle DGE + \angle EGF$. Therefore $\angle DGF > \angle EGF$ since $\angle DGE > 0$, and using the equality, $\angle DFG > \angle EGF$.

Comment: You're using CN5 (common notion), but I don't understand how can you compare angles from different planes, it is the first instance of such an operation

Comment: You are not comparing angles from different planes, since all the angles in this answer are contained in the second diagram (DGFE). If you wanted a proof from Euclidean axioms you should have specifically asked in the question.